# How to increment minute to current time in python

Tags: python, linux

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

print("Current Time =", current_time )
```

**Result** :

```
Current Time = 2021-03-08 03:14:52.899604
```

Now I need to increment minute by 2 here. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime.timedelta()`

```
current_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.